# How to diff a directory for only files of a specific type?

Tags: linux, bash, diff

I have a question about the diff command
if I want a recursive directory diff but only for a specific file type, how to do that?

I tried using the exclude option but can only use one pattern only:

```
$ diff /destination/dir/1 /destination/dir/2 -r -x *.xml
```

with the command I can only exclude xml file type, even though there are files in the folder image type (`png`, `gif`, `jpg`), `txt`, `php`, etc

how to diff only certain file types.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10131908/2707864

Comment: So are you trying to diff files of specific type or to exclude those files from diffing? The question doesn't correlates to the description..

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can specify `-x` more than once.

```
diff -x '*.foo' -x '*.bar' -x '*.baz' /destination/dir/1 /destination/dir/2
```

From the Comparing Directories section of `info diff` (on my system, I have to do `info -f /usr/share/info/diff.info.gz`):

> To ignore some files while comparing directories, use the '-x
>   PATTERN' or '--exclude=PATTERN' option.  This option ignores any files
>   or subdirectories whose base names match the shell pattern PATTERN.
>   Unlike in the shell, a period at the start of the base of a file name
>   matches a wildcard at the start of a pattern.  You should enclose
>   PATTERN in quotes so that the shell does not expand it.  For example,
>   the option **-x '*.[ao]'** ignores any file whose name ends with '.a' or
>   '.o'.
>
> This option accumulates if you specify it more than once.  For
>   example, using the options **-x 'RCS' -x '*,v'** ignores any file or
>   subdirectory whose base name is 'RCS' or ends with ',v'.

Comment: Mine (ubuntu 10.04) doesn't have these lines. I've also tried and it didn't work. I guess this is a new version.

Answer (score 27):

Taken from ( a version of) the man page:

```
-x PAT  --exclude=PAT
  Exclude files that match PAT.

-X FILE    --exclude-from=FILE
  Exclude files that match any pattern in FILE.
```

So it looks like `-x` only accepts one pattern as you report but if you put all the patterns you want to exclude in a file (presumably one per line) you could use the second flag like so:

```
$ diff /destination/dir/1 /destination/dir/2 -r -X exclude.pats
```

where exclude.pats is:

```
*.jpg
*.JPG
*.xml
*.XML
*.png
*.gif
```

Comment: You can find all file extensions within your folder except for the <my-ext> extension with the following command line: `find . -type f -not -name '*.<my-ext>' | xargs -I% basename '%' | awk -F . 'NF > 1 { print "*." $NF}; NF == 1 { print $NF }' | sort | uniq > exclude.pats`

Comment: I wish I'd noticed John's comment earlier, but on macOs/bash I came to a similar solution to produce the exclusion file with several patterns to keep: `find . -not -name "*.c" -and -not -name "*.h" -and -type f -print0 | xargs -0 basename | grep -E '.*\..+' | sed 's/\./\//g' | xargs basename | xargs printf '*.%s\n' | sort | uniq > X-FILE` I want to believe that helps, maybe on Linux too. (In this example a single `-name "*.[ch]"` is okay, but it's not very illustrative)

Answer (score 19):

You can also use find with -exec to call diff:

```
cd /destination/dir/1
find . -name *.xml -exec diff {} /destination/dir/2/{} \;
```

Answer (score 9):

The lack of a complementary --include ... .

We can do one workaround, a exclude file with all files but what we want include. So we create `file1` with a find all files which don't have extensions that we want include, `sed` catch the filename and is just :

```
diff --exclude-from=file1  PATH1/ PATH2/
```

For example:

```
find  PATH1/ -type f | grep --text -vP "php$|html$" | sed 's/.*\///' | sort -u > file1 
diff PATH1/ PATH2/ -rq -X file1
```

Comment: Super useful one-liner, thx. On Mac OSX grep is slightly different and it becomes  
`find  PATH1/ -type f | grep --text -v -e "php$" -e
html$" | sed 's/.*\///' | sort -u > file1 
diff PATH1/ PATH2/ -rq -X file1`

Answer (score 3):

I used the following command to find the diff of all `*.tmpl` files between `DIR1` and `DIR2`. In my case this didn't yield any false positives, but it may for you, depending on the contents of your DIRS.

`diff --brief DIR1 DIR2 | grep tmpl`

Answer (score 3):

Whilst it does not avoid the actual `diff` of other files, if your goal is to produce a patch file, or similar then you can use `filterdiff` from the `patchutils` package, e.g. to patch only your `.py` changes:

```
diff -ruNp /path/1 /path/2 | filterdiff -i "*.py" | tee /path/to/file.patch
```

Comment: This is the right answer. I'm confused why it only has one vote. filterdiff is designed specifically for this as far as I can tell, and it's not part of some obscure package- anyone that has diffutils almost certainly can easily install patchutils. 

Enough ranting, thank you for this as I wasn't familiar with it. Happy to throw away my find + sed abominations

Answer (score 2):

In case you find it convenient, you could use the following `Makefile`. Just run: "make patch"

```
#Makefile for patches

#Exlude following file endings
SUFFIX += o
SUFFIX += so
SUFFIX += exe
SUFFIX += pdf
SUFFIX += swp

#Exlude following folders
FOLDER += bin
FOLDER += lib
FOLDER += Image
FOLDER += models

OPTIONS = Naur

patch: 
    rm test.patch
    diff -$(OPTIONS) \
    $(foreach element, $(SUFFIX) , -x '*.$(element)') \
    $(foreach element, $(FOLDER) , -x '$(element)*') \
        org/ new/ > test.patch  

unpatch: 
    rm test.unpatch
    diff -$(OPTIONS) \
    $(foreach element, $(SUFFIX) , -x '*.$(element)') \
    $(foreach element, $(FOLDER) , -x '$(element)*') \
    new/ org/ > test.unpatch
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to differ sources and keep it simple:

```
diff -rqx "*.a" -x "*.o" -x "*.d" ./PATH1 ./PATH2 | grep "\.cpp " | grep "^Files"
```

Remove the last grep if you want to get the files which exist in only one of the paths.

Comment: I like simplicity :-) In german change `grep "^Files"` to `grep "^Dateien"`

Answer (score 1):

The lack of a complementary --include makes it necessary to use such convoluted heuristic patterns as

```
*.[A-Zb-ik-uw-z]*
```

to find (mostly) java files!