# make diff to ignore symbolic link

Tags: linux, diff, patch

My project has the following structure

```
/project/config.mk
/project/dir1/config.mk -> ../config.mk
/project/dir2/config.mk -> ../config.mk
```

When I used `diff` to create the patch file, the `/project/config.mk` was done correctly, but the two symbolic links got some problems. They were both  treated as new files, the diff sections were the whole content of the `config.mk` file. I tried to find a `diff` option to disable following symbolic link, but there is no such option available. Any suggestions are appreciated.

As Overbose's suggestion, I create this script. It works. Thank everyone for taking time answering.

```
#!/bin/sh -v
ori_dir=$1
new_dir=$2
patch_file=./patch_file
if [ -f ${patch_file} ]
then
        rm ${patch_file}
fi
ori_files=`cd ${ori_dir} ; find ./ -type f ! -type l`
for i in ${ori_files} ; do 
        if [ -f ${ori_dir}/$i ] 
        then
                if [ -f ${new_dir}/$i ]
                then
                        diff -rup ${ori_dir}/$i ${new_dir}/$i >> ${patch_file}
                fi
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use find in the following way:

```
find . ! -type l
```

This option should skip following symbolic links. Use that command to locate your file before running diff.

Comment: may you please provide the cmd?

Comment: @dien: sorry.. i just tried -P option but it doesn't work like i was expecting. anyway if you need to calculate diff only on regular file you can use: find . -type f

Comment: @dien: for the complete command : now how are you giving the input to the diff command? do you use a script?

Comment: Hi Overbose, `find . ! -type l` works, it lists only non symbolic link files. How can I feed these outputs to diff cmd? (my two directories are project.origin and project, I have already invoked `find ./project.origin ! -type l`). Thank again!

Comment: @dien: now how are you doing that? if you haven't still do anything you can write a script to do that. I think it's a bit tricky do achieve that solution in just one line command. Store the file results into 2 list and then compare each other.

Answer (score 23):

In GNU diff v3.3 there is now an option --no-dereference that does the trick

Comment: The `--no-dereference` option is described by `diff --help` but not mentioned on the man page on Ubuntu Xenial Xerus (16.04) and Raspian Jessie (8).

Answer (score 4):

If you add lines like:

```
dir1/config.mk
dir2/config.mk
```

to a file `.ignore-diff`

then you can execute `diff(1)` like this:

```
diff -ur -X .ignore-diff
```

Comment: Broken symbolic links still seem to raise an error, even when ignored like this.

Answer (score 0):

As a summary of what I did try. Working solution was to use the --no-dereference for my case.

for the -X option, you can get help with this link : [stackoverflow.com : how-do-you-diff-a-directory-for-only-files-of-a-specific-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775377/how-do-you-diff-a-directory-for-only-files-of-a-specific-type)

```or-tag-here
# max diff
diff -ruN ~/xxx-web/ ~/www/xxx/xxx-web/ > ~/xxx-web/20180523-diff.patch
# but may get too much symbolic link following, so in GNU diff v3.3 use :
diff --no-dereference -ruN ~/xxx-web/ ~/www/xxx/xxx-web/ > ~/xxx-web/20180523-diff.patch

## if no options available, you can try a solution that do not seem to work under 3.3 :
# find . -type l > .diffignore
## passing direct file will not work, it require file pattern ?
# diff -ruN -x .diffignore 
## passing with xargs do not seem to work the way below on 3.3 ...
# diff -ruN $(cat .diffignore | xargs -L1 echo "-x ")
# diff -ruN $(cat .diffignore | xargs -i echo "-x '{}'" | sed 's,\./vivaoresto-web/,*,g') \
# inFolder outFolder > diff.patch
# if you wanna apply your path in the source directory :
cd ~/www/xxx/xxx-web/
patch -p1 < ~/xxx-web/20180523-diff.patch
```