# Only include files that match a given pattern in a recursive diff

Tags: shell, unix, diff

How can you perform a recursive diff of the files in two directories (a and b):

```
$ diff -r a b
```

but only look at files whose name matches a given pattern. For example, using the same syntax available in the find command, this would look like:

```
$ diff -r a b -name "*crazy*"
```

which would show diffs between files with the same name and path in a and b, which have "crazy" in their name.

Effectively, I'm looking for the opposite of the --exclude option which is available in diff.

Comment: I agree that this would be useful.  `grep` has an `--include` flag

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Perhaps this is a bit indirect, but it ought to work. You can use `find` to get a list of files that *don't* match the pattern, and then "exclude" all those files:

```
find a b -type f ! -name 'crazy' -printf '%f\n' | diff -r a b -X -
```

The `-X -` will make `diff` read the patterns from stdin and exclude anything that matches.  This should work provided your files don't have funny chars like `*` or `?` in their names. The only downside is that your diff won't include the `find` command, so the listed `diff` command is not that useful.

(I've only tested it with GNU `find` and `diff`).

**EDIT**:

Since only non-GNU `find` doesn't have `-printf`, `sed` could be used as an alternative:

```
find a b -type f ! -name '*crazy*' -print | sed -e 's|.*/||' | diff -X - -r a b
```

That's also assuming that non-GNU `diff` has `-X` which I don't know.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has to work on Mac OS X, and I see from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752818/why-does-macs-find-not-have-the-option-printf that BSD's find doesn't have a -printf option. So there's apparently no nice to way to make a BSD and GNU compatible command.

Comment: @EdwardD'Souza Consider [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) if you want to get GNU tools on OSX.

Comment: Thanks @FatalError; could you please edit the first part of your command so that it only passes in files in 'a' and 'b', and not all files in the current in the directory? Something like:

`( (cd a && find . -type f ! -name *crazy* -print) && (cd b && find . -type f ! -name *crazy* -print) )`

Comment: @EdwardD'Souza Sure thing. I updated it with what I think should work (once again I'm really only familiar with the GNU flavor of the tools). If that doesn't work, I will update it to your suggestion.

Comment: @FatalError I'm unclear as to what "your diff won't include the find command" means.  You are saying that files with the name "find" will be excluded because the word "find" is piped to the `-X`?  Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make it work with `-X -`, so I used a different approach - let `find` find the files recursively according to my requirements and let `diff` compare individual files:

```
a="/your/dir"
b="/your/other/dir"
for f in $(find $a -name "*crazy*" | grep -oP "^$a/\K.*"); do
  diff -u $a/$f $b/$f
done
```

Or, in one line:

```
a="/your/dir" && b="/your/other/dir" && for f in $(find $a -name "*crazy*" | grep -oP "^$a/\K.*"); do diff -u $a/$f $b/$f; done
```

This `grep -oP "^$a/\K.*"` is used to extract the path relative to the directory `a`, i.e. it removes `/your/dir/` from `/your/dir/and/a/file`, to make it `and/a/file`.